# How much memory does it take for a structure that contains array of function pointers?

Tags: c, memory, structure

I have a structure written for a hypothetical CPU:

```
struct s {
  int m;
  void (*foo[13])(int);
  char s;

};
```

If address space is 63 bits wide, and if one byte is 21 bits(char is 21 bits), short, int and long are 42 bits and long long is 168 bits, do I put the pointers in long long type, because they can't fit in char, short, int or long? Do I need 13*long long(168 bits) to store 13 function pointers?

Comment: Have you tried invoking `printf("%zx", sizeof(struct s))`?

Comment: What platform has 21 bit chars and 63 bit pointers?

Comment: Seems like homework question to me.

Comment: @klutt Probably `printf("%zx\n", sizeof(struct s))`...

Comment: If for some reason you need to hold pointers in an integer type, use `intptr_t`.

Comment: Clearly, this is a homework assignment and uses a hypothetical CPU.  Since addresses are 63 bits or 3 bytes of 21 bits each, the probability is that you need 3x13= 39 bytes for the array.  But it is not guaranteed that function pointers are the same size as object pointers.  But the information given doesn’t indicate any alternative size for function pointers.

Comment: Yes, this is a hypothetical CPU. I don't have any addititional information about the size of the function pointers so I assume they are the same size as the pointers to objects. @JonathanLeffler

Comment: *this is a hypothetical CPU* The problem seems under-specified and IMO therefore has no "correct" answer.  What is the alignment restriction on function pointers?  Do they have to be aligned on 4-byte (84-bit) boundaries, for example?

Comment: If I had _attribute(packed)_ at the end of the structure,is that changing something?

Comment: Pointers don't have to be exactly the same size as any existing integral type. Function pointers can be just about any size. I can propose a reasonable implementation on this platform that has 1 byte wide function pointers. Or 2 or 3 byte. There is simply not enough data in the question. Your professor may or may not be happy to hear this.

Comment: Assuming a flat memory model (no segmentation), your pointer type should be at least as wide as your address space - 63 bits.  Pointer types don't have to be representable as integers, and pointers to different types don't all have to be the same size.

Answer (score 0):

The representation of (function) pointers is implementation dependent. An implementation typically will (for a linear address space) use something resembling one of the longer integral types; but there is no requirement to do so: The pointer may well be 3 or 4 or 5 bytes long, and on your architecture probably will be ;-). (n.m. makes the valid point that they could also potentially have a size of 1 byte, limiting, I assume, the number of functions to 2^21-1; that would actually also be a good guess for the implementation you describe.)

The alignment requirements — or recommendations (to avoid slow loads) — are architecture and implementation dependent. Aligning the data trades space for higher speed: aligned data can be written and read faster, but the alignment requires padding.

Compilers often offer means to trade speed for better space efficiency, like `#pragma pack`. The exact changes in the layout for a packed structure are, like the means to achieve it, implementation dependent; but absent contradicting information I would assume that there is no padding in a packed struct. (You can and should prove that in your program by checking `sizeof(struct s)`). The reason for not expecting any padding in a packed struct is the use case of mapping it to a hardware interface of a predefined layout.

For a definite answer without running a program we need the relevant parts of the compiler documentation so that we know the size of function pointers and the effect of packing.

Comment: But this hypothetical CPU is not using powers-of-two for sizes.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I corrected to  `sizeof char` in one place...

Comment: And if I had _attribute_(packed) at the end, does that mean structure doesn't contain padding bits between fields?

Comment: @miki1307 `_attribute_(packed)` is non-standard.  How do you know your hypothetical CPU even supports a non-standard extension like that?

Comment: @AndrewHenle I have the same structure, and the only difference is that it has _attribute_(packed) at the end. It's a homework question.

Comment: @miki That is implementation and architecture dependent. [Some architectures](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.faqs/ka15414.html) can access unaligned data, but usually slower. In architectures who can't support that the compiler has to produce code which performs multiple read/writes and combines the data accordingly. The means to tell the compiler to pack a struct are not standardized, and their effect is implementation defined (obviously). A 4 byte integer may end up at a 1-byte or at a 2-byte border; the documentation must specify that.

Comment: If we assume compiles can support  _attribute(packed)_ then we wouldn't have padding bits between structure's fileds?

Comment: This answer is sort of not wrong, but it is not helpful. First, a size cannot be a multiple of 8, any more than the size of a car can be 8 or the length of a pen can be 8. It has to be 8 **units** of something. Do you mean 8 bits, 8 bytes, or something else? Regarding being a multiple of `sizeof char` (should be `sizeof(char)`), this is not just “Typically”; it is necessary. `sizeof(char)` is always 1, and every `sizeof` result is a multiple of 1. And the answer seems completely oblivious to the contrived nature of the question, indicating it is an academic exercise about the C standard.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thanks for taking the time to point out the deficiencies...btw, being oblivious was intentional because a proper answer should not depend on the implementation specifics (but point them out).

Comment: @miki1307 The effect of `attribute(packed)` is not standardized. One can *assume* that there is no padding (for the hardware mapping or general efficiency reasons), but there is no guarantee. I updated my answer.